# Compare Dynamic Lists Power BI

Tags: filter, powerbi, conditional-statements, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table ("Issues") which I am creating in PowerBI from a JIRA data connector, so this changes each time I refresh it. I have three columns I am using

1. Form Name
2. Effort
3. Status

I created a second table and have summarized the Form Names and obtained the Total Effort:

SUMMARIZE(Issues,Issues[Form Name],"Total Effort",SUM(Issues[Effort (Days)]))

[image]

But I also want to add in a column for

4. Total Effort for each form name **where the Status field is "Done"**

My issue is that I don't know how to compare both tables / form names since these might change each time I refresh the table.

I need to write a conditional, something like

**For each form name, print the total effort for each form name, print the total effort for each form name where the status is done**

I have tried SUMX, CALCULATE, SUM, FILTER but cannot get these to work - can someone help, please?

Comment: May be M can help, with DAX, most probaly, you have nothing to do. What are names looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to add a column to your summarized table that sums "Effort" only when the Status is set to 'Done' -- then this is the right place to use CALCULATE.

```
Table = 
SUMMARIZE(
    Issues,
    Issues[Form Name],
    "Total Effort", SUM(Issues[Effort]),
    "Total Effort (Done)", CALCULATE(SUM(Issues[Effort]), Issues[Status] = "Done")
)
```

Here is a quick capture of what some of the mock data that I used to test this looks like.  The Matrix is just the mock data with [Form Name] on the rows and [Status] on the columns.   The last table shows the 'summarized' data calculated by the DAX above.  You can compare this to the values in the matrix and see that they tie out.

[image]